# Probability of positive given a finite number of positives

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to find a distribution that matches the following scenario, but my prob skills are very rusty.

I have $K=2$ types of jelly beans. I pick each jelly bean of type $k$ with probability $p_k$. There are a finite number of jelly beans of each type. Once there are no more jelly beans of a type, I will always pick the remaining type. $p_k$ is not dependent on population.

In other words, I pick with bernoulli pmf until one color runs out, then I always pick the remaining color.

**e.g.**  I have $3$ red beans and $7$ green beans,  I pick a red bean with $Pr=0.1$ and green with $Pr=0.9$ (probabilities ARE NOT related to population, they are part of a separate process). Once I've picked all $3$ red beans then I will always pick green OR (less likely, but possible) I’ve picked all $7$ green beans before getting all $3$ red beans then I would always pick red after that. (this is not the hypergeometric distribution).

I am looking for the pmf, i.e. $P(x=K)$ as whole.

Comment: This is unclear.  Distribution of what?  You use the letter $K$ to denote three different things (the number of bowls, the index of a given bowl, and the color of the beans in that bowl).  I'm not sure you need to use it at all.  I assume $p$ means something like the probability of choosing the first bowl (with $1-p$ then being the probability of choosing the second), yes?

Comment: Ty, I will update. Each bowl K has only K colored jelly beans. You can assume that each time you pick, its a bernoulli trial

Comment: sorry, still not clear.  Don't use the letter $K$ over and over again to mean different things.  You only have two bowls.  Bowl $1$ and bowl $2$.  What is in bowl $1$?what is in bowl $2$?  What is $x$?

Comment: Let’s not work about the bowls. There are red and green jelly beans. I have prob p of picking red and 1-p of picking green until one or the other is gone, then I would always pick the remaining color. I want the pmf

Comment: @lulu I’ve updated to remove mention of bowls. Is that better?

Comment: I just don't understand the question.  Are you asking for the probability that the $n^{th}$ draw will be red?  But, just use the Law of Total Probability.  If $n$ is less than the total there are three mutually exclusive cases...either the red are gone, the blue are gone, or neither are gone.  The probability of each case is easily computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let there be $r$ red balls and $g$ green balls. Pick red balls with probability $p$ and green balls with probability $(1-p)$.

Suppose we are drawing balls and that we run out of green balls first.  Obviously we need at least $g$ draws to run out of green balls.  Thus for $g \leq m < r+g$, the probability that the last green ball is picked as the $m^{th}$ ball is:

$${{m-1}\choose{g-1}}p^{m-g}(1-p)^{g}$$

Which is the probability of having drawn all greens, filling out the rest of the spaces with reds, and then being able to move around the order of drawing the $g-1$ green balls. On the other hand, if we run out of red balls first, the probability that the last red ball is drawn at position $r \leq m <r+g$ is:

$${{m-1}\choose{r-1}}p^{r}(1-p)^{m-r}$$

The probability we run out of green balls first is:

$$\sum_{m=g}^{r+g-1}{{m-1}\choose{g-1}}p^{m-g}(1-p)^{g}$$

With the analgous sum for red balls first.  If you specifically want the pmf of the $x^{th}$ draw being a certain color, there are two cases: Case $1$ is $x \leq \min\{r,g\}$; Case $2$ is $\min\{r,g\} < x $.  Case $1$ for draw $x$ is just $\mathbb{P}(x = r) = p$.  For case 2:

$$\mathbb{R}[x = r] = 1\left(\sum_{m=g}^{x}{{m-1}\choose{g-1}}p^{m-g}(1-p)^{g}\right) + p\left(1-\sum_{m=g}^{x}{{m-1}\choose{g-1}}p^{m-g}(1-p)^{g}-\sum_{m=r}^{x}{{m-1}\choose{r-1}}p^{r}(1-p)^{m-r}\right) + 0\left(\sum_{m=r}^{x}{{m-1}\choose{r-1}}p^{r}(1-p)^{m-r}\right)$$

i.e. with the probability we run out of the green before $x$ plus the probability we run out of neither times $p$ since it is constant.  If we run out of red balls before $x$ then the probability of drawing one is zero.

---

**Edit:** Actually that formula should hold all the time since ${{n}\choose{k}}=0$ for $n < k$

Comment: This looks good and makes sense. Do you know if this is a ‘known’/named distribution? The final pmf looks like it can get simplified quite a bit.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like the [Negative Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).  I assume that there is a way to rephrase your question in this way.

Comment: It is very very close, the only difference is the number of successes AND the number of failures is finite. and it doesn't take into account the fact that you are looking at the likelihood of failure/success, not the # of failure for # of successes.